# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object with PDO 

Tags: php

I have a function which uses:

```
require_once("connect.php");

function get_username($uid){
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid= ?");

try {
    $stmt->execute(array($uid));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage(); exit;
}

      $row = $stmt->fetch();
      return($row['username']);
}

$id = 1;
echo get_username($id);
```

But it says :

```
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

I'm a bit confused on what this means i have wrong, i'm wondering if its because I am using it in a function ?

EDIT:

My Connect script¬

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test_db;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'test_user';
$password = 'test_pass';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
```

Comment: first create object of $pdo and then use, it is so simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's because you're using it in a function. `$pdo` is in the global scope, and is not in the scope of the function.

You either need to access the `$pdo` global by referencing it in the function as a global variable:

```
function get_username($uid){
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid= ?");
```

Or pass `$pdo` in when you call the function

```
function get_username($uid, $pdo){

...
...
}

get_username( $id, $pdo);
```

Comment: Best choice is the second one, this is a non-OOP approach to dependency injection.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the advice ! :) Will tick your answer when it lets me!